# Python Discord Bot - Seems to not be reciving messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot, every time I type a message that it is supposed to respond to, nothing happens. In the log you get an output like this:

**Username** said:  (**Channel**)

This is my bot file:

```
import discord
import responses

async def send_messages(message, user_message):
    try:
        response = response.handle_response(user_message)
        await message.channel.send(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def run_discord_bot():
    TOKEN = "**Token**"
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)


    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} is now running')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return 
        
        username = str(message.author)
        user_message = str(message.content)
        channel = str(message.channel)
        print(f"{username} said: {user_message} ({channel})")

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

This is my responses file:

```
def handle_response(message) -> str:
    p_message = message.lower()
    if p_message == "Hello":
        return "Hey, Welcome to the server. Check #faq for a guide to the server"
    
    if p_message == "!Help":
        return "`This is a help message`"
    
    return "I didnt quite get that message"
```

Note: I do have all of the Privileged Gateway Intents enabled in the Developer Portal

I'm not exactly sure what is wrong here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing `intents = discord.Intents.default()` with `intents = discord.Intents.all()`. Recheck if you have enabled all the intents in your Discord Developer Portal. Where are you using `send_messages(...)`? You might want to add something like `await send_messages(message, user_message)` as the last line in `on_message`. And you seem to be using the wrong spelling (it should be `responses` instead of `response` in your code).